# VRTK & SteamVR Local Multiplayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vrtk

How do I go about inserting another independent camera rig which can be used to navigate using mouse & keyboard in the same scene as the VR player, together with the VR player, with an independent camera view? Does VRTK/SteamVR natively have this feature?

In other words, I'd like to know how to implement asymmetrical local multiplayer, similar to the 'Panoptic' demo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes [VRTK_Simulator](https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/docs/vrtk_simulator) is the script available:

> To test a scene it is often necessary to use the headset to move to a
>   location. This increases turn-around times and can become cumbersome.
>
> The simulator allows navigating through the scene using the keyboard
>   instead, without the need to put on the headset. One can then move
>   around (also through walls) while looking at the monitor and still use
>   the controllers to interact.
>
> Supported movements are: forward, backward, strafe left, strafe right,
>   turn left, turn right, up, down.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, but I don't think this is what I was looking for. My understanding is that the VR Camera and the VR Simulator Camera rigs are mutually exclusive, ie: they can not be used simultaneously and therefore can not achieve the local asymmetric multiplayer result that I am after.

Comment: Did you apply this script and tested?

Comment: Yep, I use it regularly when testing and it works as described. It did not however offer a solution to my question as far as I am aware.

Comment: so what actual problem? can you describe it a bit more in your question.

Comment: Your answer ignores the 'another independent camera rig' and 'local multiplayer' aspect of my question. By default, the VRTK Simulator replaces the headset. I need the headset to remain active in the scene, while a _second, independent, keyboard & mouse controlled camera_ is operated _simultaneously_ from the screen in the same scene.